# Using SafeCom G4 Administrator DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I'm working with SafeCom (print server) and figured out that they have a [Administrator DLL Programmer’s Manual](http://www.netprint.se/bibliotek/SafeCom/Manualer/SafeCom%20G4/SafeCom%20G4%20API%20Administrator/safecom_g4_administrator_dll_programmers_manual_60827-01.pdf). As a proof of concept I wanted to make a small C# application that sends and retrieves data using this library. I've managed to insert a user object by calling LoginByLogon() followed by AddUser().

However, I'm not able to retrieve/return a user struct by calling LoginByLogon() followed by GetUser. I can see that ptrTemp is set (not null), but all properties in newStructure are still null. I don't fully understand PInvoke yet, so I hope someone here can enlighten me a little. :)

I'm for now importing the following:

```
[DllImport("scAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int sc_LoginByLogon(string szIpAddr, string szUserName, string szPassword);

[DllImport("scAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int sc_Logoff();

[DllImport("scAPI.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon(string szUserLogon, out IntPtr ppUserInfo);

[DllImport("scAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern short sc_AddUser(ref sUserInfoApiV4 ppUserInfo, double fAccount, double FLowLimit, ref int pNewId);
```

Define my structs:

```
struct SYSTEMTIME
{
    short wYear;
    short wMonth;
    // short wDayOfWeek;
    short wDay;
    short wHour;
    short wMinute;
    short wSecond;
    short wMilliseconds;
    public static implicit operator SYSTEMTIME(DateTime time)
    {
        return new SYSTEMTIME
        {
            wYear = (short)time.Year,
            wMonth = (short)time.Month,
            wDay = (short)time.Day,
            //   wDayOfWeek = (short)time.DayOfWeek,
            wHour = (short)time.Hour,
            wMinute = (short)time.Minute,
            wSecond = (short)time.Second,
            wMilliseconds = (short)time.Millisecond
        };
    }
    public static implicit operator DateTime(SYSTEMTIME time)
    {
        return new DateTime(time.wYear, time.wMonth, time.wDay, time.wHour, time.wMinute, time.wSecond, time.wMilliseconds);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Card
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)]
    public string m_szCardNo; //Card number
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string m_szPINCode; //PIN code - zero terminated
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
    public string m_szPUKCode; //PUK code - zero terminated
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
public struct sUserInfoApiV4
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 m_nStructLength; //Length of the struct including this field
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nVersion; //Version Number (set to 4)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nSubVersion; //Version of Reserved (set to 0)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public byte[] m_achReserved; // Get room for m_nAccessRights
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nUserType; //USER_STRUCT (uses as UserType - BitFields)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nUserId; //Unique id identifying the user
    public int m_nSubRights; // Sub version 2
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nNotUsed1; // Sub version 5
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
    public string m_wzFullName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
    public string m_wzDescription;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
    public string m_wzEMail;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 21)]
    public string m_wzUserLogon; //Asc-ii string identifying the user
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    public string m_wzPassword; //Asc-ii string password         
    public Card card;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nLogonFails; //Number of failed logins
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_bUserLocked; //Unlocked(0), Locked(1)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_bUserDisabled; //Not Disable(0), Open(1)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_bAvoidPin; //Pin Enabled(0), Pin disabled (1)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_bPrintAll; //Print All when card is slid - Yes(1) No(0)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_bCardOpen; //PIN code assigned(0), Awaiting pin assignment/Outstanding PUK(1)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nBillingModel; //None(0), BillingDialog(1)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nAccountingModel; //None(0), Tracking(1), Pay(2)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nUserRights; // None(0)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_bAllowEncryption; // The user uses encryption YES(1) NO(0)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    bool m_bAllowCheckPrinting; // The user is allowed to receives checks YES(1) NO(0)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    bool m_bAllowPmail; // The user is allowed distribution YES(1) NO(0)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    bool m_bDenyRetain; // User allowed to retain his documents. New in SubVersion 3
    public int m_lCreationDate;
    public int m_lLastLogin;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nServerId; // HomeServer of this user.
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nDomainId; // New in Subversion 1 - Reference to the windows domain the user are located in
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nTreeNodeId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nNid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 51)]
    public string m_wzCostCode; // Cost center, new in SubVersion 3
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public unsafe struct SCardInfoApiV4
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 m_nStructLength; // Length of entire struct
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nVersion; // Version (short)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short m_nSubVersion; // Subversion of reserved, set to 1 (short)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public byte[] m_achReserved; // Reserved for protocol expansion (fixed char)
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nCardId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int m_nUserId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)]
    public string m_achCardNo; // originalt fixed char [40]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string m_achReservedPinCode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
    public string m_achReservedPukCode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 51)]
    public string m_achDescription;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    int m_nCreatorId;
    SYSTEMTIME m_sCreated;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1)]
    public string m_nUseLifeTime;  //originalt char
    SYSTEMTIME m_sLifeStart;
    SYSTEMTIME m_sLifeEnd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    int m_nSourceId; // Sub version 1
}
```

And finally my methods:

```
 public int LoginByLogon(string ipAddr, string userLogon, string password)
        {
            return sc_LoginByLogon(ipAddr, userLogon, password);
        }

        public int Logoff()
        {
            return sc_Logoff();
        }

        public sUserInfoApiV4 GetUser(string userLogon)
        {
            sUserInfoApiV4 tmpUserInfo = new sUserInfoApiV4();

            IntPtr ptrTemp = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tmpUserInfo));
            sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon(userLogon, out ptrTemp);

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(tmpUserInfo, ptrTemp, false);

            sUserInfoApiV4 newStructure;
            newStructure = (sUserInfoApiV4)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrTemp, typeof(sUserInfoApiV4));

            return newStructure;
        }

        public unsafe int AddUser(string usercode, string email, string pinCode, string fullName)
        {
            sUserInfoApiV4 sUserstruct = new sUserInfoApiV4();
            int sizeOfstruct = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(sUserInfoApiV4));
            IntPtr pSUserstruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeOfstruct);      //Make note of memory used
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sUserstruct, pSUserstruct, false);

            sUserstruct.m_wzUserLogon = usercode;
            sUserstruct.card.m_szCardNo = usercode;            //Card number same as logon
            sUserstruct.card.m_szPINCode = pinCode;
            sUserstruct.m_wzFullName = fullName;
            sUserstruct.m_wzEMail = email;
            sUserstruct.m_nUserRights = 3;                    //Standard user rights
            sUserstruct.m_nAccountingModel = 2;                //Pay user                                    
            sUserstruct.m_nVersion = 4;                         //Safecom version
            sUserstruct.m_nStructLength = sizeOfstruct;
            sUserstruct.m_bAvoidPin = 1;                        // Disable PIN
            int userId = 0;                                     //Value of variable not used, just to initialize the variable. Used as pointer for return value. Index number for user in db
            int* userIndex = &userId;

            int nRes = sc_AddUser(ref sUserstruct, 0, 0, ref *userIndex);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pSUserstruct);        // Release memory 
            pSUserstruct = IntPtr.Zero;               // used by pointer.

            return nRes;
        }
```

Comment: The dll has four methods (sc_LoginByLogon,sc_Logoff,sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon, and sc_AddUser).  And each method has a parameter list just like c#.  In c# the calling of methods is managed while the calls to c++ is unmanaged.  Managed means the parameters are put into the execution stack.  Unmanaged the parameters are put into global static memory space before being put on the execution stack.

Comment: A string in c++ is equivalent to a byte[] terminated with '\0'.  So you need to convert the c# string using : IntPtr ptr =  Marshal.StringToBSTR(string);  And int sc_GetUserInfoByUserLogon(IntPtr szUserLogon, out IntPtr ppUserInfo);

Comment: Thanks for the tip @jdweng, but all properties of newStructure are still null even if I convert the string to a IntPtr.

Comment: Is the return int = 0?  Section 4.2 will define all the valid return codes.  The pointer will be null if the method cannot find the userLogin. The userLogin that you added may be bad.  The byte[] used in sc_LoginByLogon() may not be matching what you are using to retrieve user.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The login function returns 1, so I assume that works as intended. The return int for GetUser is 1, but the pointer has a value, so it's failing at some point. I know that the user exists.

Comment: I wonder if there's something wrong with my DLLImport. If I omit CharSet and  CallingConvention I get an error saying the stack is unbalanced, but I get no error when using them like I do initially (as in my first post). Do I have to make a change here?

Comment: You need both CharSet and CallingConvention.  I would start by fixing the return for sc_AddUser to an Int (not short).  Then make sure all the methods are returning a zero.   Also check that the first property of the structures m_nStructLength actually matches the size the the c# compiler assigns by using either sizeof() or Marshal.SizeOf()